# What will be the product of 1 eqv Benzene reacts with 1eqv H2?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, stoichiometry, hydrogen, physical-organic-chemistry

[image]

how equivalent concept is applied in the above problem, Kindly help me out with the answer and proper explanation.
As, I am getting confused in mole concept and equivalent concept here.

Comment: This is very dependent on the conditions and the catalyst used.

Comment: @Waylander I wouldn't say *very* dependent. It took chemists the best part of a century to find conditions that don't mostly give cyclohexane.

Comment: Those last edits make the question worse not better by leaving out a possible explanation for the confusion. We need to see what your thoughts were or it looks like we are doing your homework, which is a solid reason to close the question.

Answer (score 6):

**The answer makes sense (and doesn't break the law of chemical equivalence) when you consider the reactivity and stability of the intermediates in the reaction**

Hydrogenation of benzene proceeds in several steps (which is intuitively obvious as a single hydrogen molecule can only add two hydrogens to a benzene ring).

But the intermediate that results from a single hydrogenation step, cyclohexadiene, is *more reactive* than benzene so the further hydrogenation happens faster than further hydrogenation of benzene. The same is true for the product of that reaction, cyclohexene. So, under simple hydrogenations where there is not enough hydrogen to fully hydrogenate the remaining benzene, you tend to get cyclohexane as a product and lots of benzene remains.

As described, the particular reaction shown only has enough hydrogen to turn 1/3 of the benzene into cyclohexane. Hence the mix of products: 2/3 benzene and 1/3 cyclohexane. And this, overall, obeys the law of chemical equivalence.

It is possible to use careful conditions and specific catalysts to change the mix of products. But it isn't easy. Benzene hydrogenation had been known for over 100 years before chemists observed cyclohexene as a product. The first industrial plant exploiting partial hydrogenation didn't open until 1990.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it clearly, but 1eqv of benzene + 1 eqv hydrogen gives 0.33 eqv cyclohexane + 0.66 benzene, but according to law of equivalence the each reactants with one equivalent we will give one equivalent of each of the product. But here it is 0.66 and 0.33 eqv. I think for mole concept it to be true but for equivalent concept I think something is wrong.

Comment: As, 1 eqv of hydrogen is not 1 mole of hydrogen same for benzene as they are reaction dependent, so also product dependent, can u rectify if I know something wrong....

Comment: @AmritenduBiswas The law or chemical equivalence is based on moles (or molecules if you want to count one molecule at a time). One mole of hydrogen can fully hydrogenate just 1/3 moles of benzene as it takes 3 hydrogen molecules to hydrogenate each molecule of benzene. The law holds up fine.

Answer (score 3):

Hydrogenation of benzene requires high temperature and high pressure of hydrogen. An equimolar mix of benzene and hydrogen (the term "*equivalent*" is unfortunate here) with catalyst and appropriate temperature $T$ and pressure $p$ might form diene but as concentrations increased diene would react much faster than benzene ether by competing for remaining hydrogen or as a source of hydrogen to form the most stable product mix, cyclohexane and benzene.

A catalyst will hasten equilibrium and give thermodynamic products unless specifically fitted to a reaction as in enzyme reactions. To form the intermediate alkenes the reaction conditions must be tailored (excess benzene) and the intermediates separated immediately from the reaction, perhaps a flow system allowing only transient contact with the catalyst and with a cold trap or trapping agent downstream, say a reversible Diels–Alder.

The question, as asked, does not arouse the student's curiosity about the chemistry and that is extremely unfortunate.